# getting error message PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::requestAndResponse()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I am new to Zend Framework. I am working on an app to search through Gmail inbox by using the class (which I added to `Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php`)

```
/**
 * do a search request
 *
 * This method is currently marked as internal as the API might change and is not
 * safe if you don't take precautions.
 *
 * @internal
 * @return array message ids
 */
public function search(array $params)
{
    $response = $this->requestAndResponse('SEARCH', $params);
    if (!$response) {
        return $response;
    }

    foreach ($response as $ids) {
        if ($ids[0] == 'SEARCH') {
            array_shift($ids);
            return $ids;
        }
    }
    return array();
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
$searchresults = $storage->search(array('search_terms'));
```

But everytime I try to run it, it shows an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::requestAndResponse() in /public_html/test06/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php on line 655

Comment: Are you patching ZF codebase to achieve what you want?!

Comment: Yes I have. Actually I am using the lib xoauth-php-samples from google code from      http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode     to access the gmail through imap and oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that requestAndResponse is not defined in the way you're calling it. I don't use ZF, but are you sure requestAndResponse accepts the 2 param you're sending. I mean ('SEARCH', $params).